# Infinite loop on checking character in a do while

Tags: c++, while-loop, boolean, infinite-loop

The goal is to calculate the percentage of marks over 10. Marks are between 0 and 20. I have an issue with the while loop when I click on 'N'. I get an infinite loop.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    float MARK, PERCENTAGE;
    int NBR_MARK, NBR_MARK_10;
    MARK = 0;
    NBR_MARK = 0;
    NBR_MARK_10 = 0;
    PERCENTAGE = 0;
    char R = 'N';

    std::cout << "Enter a mark ?" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> MARK;

    while (MARK < 0 || MARK > 20) {
        std::cout << " Please, enter a mark between 0 and 20" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> MARK;
    }

    std::cout << "Do you want to enter a new mark ?" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Click on 'O' to continue and on 'N' to stop" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> R;

    if ((R != 'N') || (R != 'n'))
        std::cout << "You will continue" << std::endl;

    do {
        std::cout << "Enter a new mark" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> MARK;
        std::cout << std::endl;

        while ((MARK < 0) || (MARK > 20)) {
            std::cout << "Please, enter a mark between 0 and 20" << std::endl;
            std::cin >> MARK;
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }

        NBR_MARK++;

        if (MARK > 10) NBR_MARK_10++;

        std::cout << "To stop press 'N'" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> R;

    }
    while ((R != 'N') || (R <= 'n'));

    PERCENTAGE = NBR_MARK_10 / NBR_MARK * 100;
    std::cout << "Le % de notes > 10 est de: " << PERCENTAGE << " %" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Typo? `(R <= 'n')`

Comment: I am a bit confused by the instructions given in your code to the user. You say "click on ..." or "press N", but you use `cin` and the user needs to hit the key and then press enter. What is the input exactly?

Comment: `while ((R != 'N') || (R <= 'n'));` This probably is causing your issue

Comment: @Caleth thank you very much for your feedback. I have corrected the typo however I still have an infinite loop when I want to stop adding marks.

Comment: @ColdCerberus thank you very much for your feedback. I have corrected it. As I have just mentioned to Caleth I do not find a way to solve the infinite loop when I select the boolean 'N'.

Comment: @idclev463035818 yes, you are right. I have translated it from french to english and it might not be properly translated. The goal is to use a character 'R' on the keybord to continue in the loop or to go outside the loop. That is specially here where I am struggling. Indeed, when I type 'N' the loop goes to infinite. Ok, now I understand your point. You mean I am typing 'N' + 'ENTER' while my code is just asking to type 'N'. I was just trying to use a boolean value to get off from the loop.

Comment: In the condition, I guess you should replace OR by AND

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    float MARK=0.0, PERCENTAGE=0.0;
    int NBR_MARK_10;
    float NBR_MARK = 0.0;
    NBR_MARK_10 = 0;
    char R = 'a';
    while(R!='N')
    {
        std::cout << "Enter a mark ?" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> MARK;

        while (MARK < 0 || MARK > 20) {
            std::cout << " Please, enter a mark between 0 and 20" << std::endl;
            std::cin >> MARK;
        }
        NBR_MARK+=1.0;
    
        if (MARK > 10) NBR_MARK_10++;
        
        std::cout << "Do you want to enter a new mark ?" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Click on 'O' to continue and on 'N' to stop" << std::endl;
        cin >> R;
    
    }
    PERCENTAGE = (NBR_MARK_10 / NBR_MARK) * 100;
    std::cout << "Le % de notes > 10 est de: " << PERCENTAGE << " %" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

use a while loop when your checking the next input of R and make sure you make one of the counter variables to float else youll end up getting percentage as zero for few testcases.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems with the code. As Sharath Chander P pointed out, there is clearly a logical issue in the code flow. Even if you press 'N' (for the first time) the code block inside do..while will execute since the condition is checked only after executing all the statements inside the do..while loop.

Now to your question on the infinite loop. It is because the expression  `while ((R != 'N') || (R <= 'n'));` will be 'true' when you press the key 'N'. When you press 'N', the value of R will be 78 (ASCII value of 'N'). Since the ASCII value of 'n' is 110, the checking `R<='n'` will return true. (Clearly 78 is less than 110.)

Since `(R!='N')` is false and `R<='n'` is true, the expression `while ((R != 'N') || (R <= 'n'));` will be evaluated as `while(false || true)`.

Since the result will be "true", the loop will continue.

Now if you press 'n' then the expression will be evaluated as `while(true || true)` that too will result in "true" and the loop will continue;